How to Simplify $M\left(\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}\right) > -k$ in terms of $x$?
I'm working with the following matrix inequality:
$$M\left(\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}\right) > -k$$
where:
$M$ is a matrix,
$x$ and $k$ are vectors, and
$\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$ represents the element-wise application of the sigmoid function on $x$.
Here the exponent is taken elementwise -
$$
\exp(-\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} 
e^{-x_1} \\
e^{-x_2} \\
\vdots \\
e^{-x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Also $x \in R^{n}$
I'd like to simplify this expression in terms of $x$ if possible. My main questions are:
Is there a way to rewrite this inequality in a more compact form involving $x$?
Are there any conditions on $M$ or $k$ that could make it easier to interpret or simplify further?
Thanks in advance for any guidance on this!
What I am trying to do - I recently derived the weakest precondition equations for a shallow neural network using scalars over here. I want to extend the derivation to use matrices and vectors. Please let me know if something is unclear.
